# What makes Iterable.map work with suspend functions?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In general, `suspend fun`s cannot be used in place of normal `fun`s.  If you try to call a `suspend fun` directly from a normal `fun`, you will get a compile-time error.

[This blog post](https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/04/parallel-map-in-kotlin/) mentions that you can do a concurrent map in Kotlin by writing

```
list.map { async { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }
```

Why does the second `map` compile?  You can't generally pass a `suspend fun` in place of a `fun`.  Is it

- that `map` is an `inline fun` and that the suspension is automatically inferred "upstream"
- that `map` is special cased somehow by Kotlin
- something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> that map is an inline fun and that the suspension is automatically inferred "upstream"

Yes. Suspend funs are checked *after* inlining. I can't see an explicit mention of this in documentation, but there is one in the [Coroutines KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md):

> Note: Suspending lambdas may invoke suspending functions in all places of their code where a non-local return statement from this lambda is allowed. That is, **suspending function calls inside inline lambdas like apply{} block are allowed, but not in the noinline nor in crossinline inner lambda expressions**. A suspension is treated as a special kind of non-local control transfer.